# How do you Set the "url" when creating a new Response()?

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm following [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/Response#Examples) example to create a mocked response for a test.

Slightly modified, it looks like this:

```
 var data = { foo: 'bar'};
 var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(data)], {type : 'application/json'});
 var init = { "status" : 200 , "statusText" : "SuperSmashingGreat!" };
 var resp = new Response(blob,init);

console.log(resp.url)

body: (...)
bodyUsed: true
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "SuperSmashingGreat!"
type: "default"
url: ""
```

this does a good job mocking the data and status however, I also want to mock `resp.url` I don't see how I can set that using the constructor and [since it's readonly] I can't set it on resp itself

```
resp.url 
>> ""
resp.url = 'www.test.com'
>> "www.test.com"
resp.url
>> ""
```

So how do I set the url?

Comment: Check this document link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response `Response.url` have an only `Read only` Permission.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/url `Response.url` is read only

Comment: So can it be initialized with a value?

Comment: @lonewarrior556 Check this example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/url

Comment: @chintankotadiya that example actually calls a fetch

Comment: @lonewarrior556 `.then` function parameter is a `Response` class object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since `url` is actually defined by an inherited getter, you can use `Object.definedProperty` to define a simple value property directly on your `Response` instance, which shadows the inherited getter property:

```
Object.defineProperty(resp, "url", { value: "foobar" });
```

---

For your own understanding, you can see the inherited getter by looking at the property descriptor of `Response.prototype.url`:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf(new Response()), 'url')
> {get: ƒ, set: undefined, enumerable: true, configurable: true}
```