# URL is empty when defining a Response object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, response

I am trying to create a Response request like that:

```json
Response { type: "basic", url: "https://mywebsite.com/download?lang=en", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "SuperSmashingGreat!"}
```

I read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/Response) how to set a new `Response` object, and I tried:

```js
var myBlob = new Blob();

var init = {
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": "SuperSmashingGreat!",
  "url": "https://mywebsite.com/download?lang=en",
  "ok": "true"
};

var myResponse = new Response(myBlob, init);

console.log(myResponse)
```

After I run it, I received this `Response` object without the url (it is empty `url: ""`):

```
{
  type: "default",
  url: "",
  redirected: false,
  status: 200,
  ok: true,
  statusText: "SuperSmashingGreat!",
  headers: Headers,
  body: ReadableStream,
  bodyUsed: false
}
```

Why it is not being set?

Comment: According to the documentation, `init` only accepts `status`, `statusText` and `headers` as keys.

Comment: Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56654119/how-do-you-set-the-url-when-creating-a-new-response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @Blair Nangle for the comment, based on [this website](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57382543/2153777).
I used:

```
Object.defineProperty(resp, "url", { value: "foobar" });
```

Full working code:

```
var myBlob = new Blob();

var init = {
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": "SuperSmashingGreat!",
  "url": "https://mywebsite.com/download?lang=en",
  "ok": "true"
};

var resp = new Response(myBlob, init);

Object.defineProperty(resp, "resp", { value: "https://mywebsite.com/download?lang=en" });
console.log(myResponse)
```